# Apply game object rotation using relative VR controller rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

I have a game object in Unity which I want to be able to rotate using my VR controller. I can kind've achieve this by doing the following...

```
bool triggerClicked = false;
Transform rightHand = Player.instance.rightHand.transform;
 
void Update () {
    if (triggerClicked) {
         transform.eulerAngles = rightHand.eulerAngles;
    }           
{
```

...but the problem is the object I want to rotate initially snaps to my controller's current rotation when I press the trigger and then works as intended. I need it to move relative to the object's initial rotation instead. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. You need to capture some initial quaternions when the trigger is first clicked and then calculate the relative differences and apply them. This prevents the initial snapping to rotation issue.

```
  private bool triggerClicked = false;
  private Transform rightHand = Player.instance.rightHand.transform;

  private Quaternion initialObjectRotation;
  private Quaternion initialControllerRotation;

  private bool set = false;

 void Update () {
     if (triggerClicked) {

         if(set == false)
            {
                initialObjectRotation= transform.rotation;
                initialControllerRotation = rightHand.rotation;
                set = true;
            }

            Quaternion controllerAngularDifference = initialControllerRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(rightHand.rotation);
            transform.rotation = controllerAngularDifference * initialObjectRotation;
     }         
     else
     {
         set = false;
     }
 {
```